# JsPlump Custom Connector's events

Tags: javascript, jsplumb, connector

I created new simple Connector using jsPlumb.
And I want to handle event in this Connector, when I stop drag my Item (a click of the mouse after dragging).

I need handle it only in Connector in depends on new position of the Item.

How can I do it?

It is my simple connector

```
    var CustomConnector = function(params) {
    var _super = jsPlumb.Connectors.AbstractConnector.apply(this, params);
    this.type = "CustomConnector";

    this._compute = function(paintInfo, paintParams) {
    //my code
    };
    };

   jsPlumbUtil.extend(CustomConnector , jsPlumb.Connectors.AbstractConnector);
   jsPlumb.registerConnectorType(CustomConnector , "CustomConnector ");
```

Comment: Please share the code or part of your code

Comment: @tracevipin , I'va updated my question. This connector works, but I don't know - how to handle events in this connector